# PHP/MySQL - too many connections issue

Tags: php, database, oop, model-view-controller, mysqli

I am developing a CMS with OOP PHP. It all was working well, but yesterday after adding a new feature it just crash. Now it retrieve this error when accessing any page:

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1040): Too many connections in
>   /var/www/html/Projects/CMS4/lib/DB.php on line 15 Connection failed:
>   1040 Too many connections Fatal error: Call to a member function
>   render() on a non-object in
>   /var/www/html/Projects/CMS4/controllers/BaseController.php on line 33

I can handle the fatal error. But, about the "too many connections" error, I understand that I am doing too many calls to new mysqli() and that maybe I could solve it by just changing the max_connections on mysql, but is this the appropriate? Or I am doing something wrong in my code that I should improve? How can I reduce my connections? This is my DB class:

DB.php

```
<?php
namespace Core;

if ( !class_exists( 'DB' ) ) {

    class DB {

        private $cxn = null;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->connect();
    }

    private function connect() {
        if ( $this->cxn !== null ) {
            return;
        }
        $this->cxn = new \mysqli( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME );
        if ( $this->cxn->connect_error ) {
            die( "Connection failed: " . $this->cxn->connect_errno . ' ' . $this->cxn->connect_error );
        }
    }

        private function create_db( $name ) {
            $sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $name";
            if( !$this->cxn->query( $sql ) ){
                die( "Error creating database: " . $this->cxn->errno . ' ' . $this->cxn->error );
            }
        }

        private function select_db( $name ) {
            if( !$this->cxn->select_db( $name ) ){
                die( "Error selecting database: " . $this->cxn->errno . ' ' . $this->cxn->error );
            }
        }

        /**
         * Create a new table in the db with the specified columns
         * @param  array $tables
         */
        public function create_tables( $tables ) {
            $sql = '';
            if ( !is_array( $tables ) ) $tables = array();

            foreach ( $tables as $name => $columns ) {
                $sql .= "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $name ($columns);";
            }

            if( !$this->cxn->multi_query( $sql ) ){
                die( "Error creating table: " . $this->cxn->errno .' '. $this->cxn->error );
            }
        }

        /**
         * Insert a row in table
         * @param  string $table
         * @param  array $data
         * @param  array $format
         * @return boolean
         */
        public function insert( $table, $data, $format ) {

            if ( empty($table) || empty($data) ) {
                return false;
            }

            //cast $data and $format to array
            $data = (array) $data;
            $format = (array) $format;

            //Build format string
            $format = $this->build_format($format);

            //prepare data
            list($fields, $placeholders, $values) = $this->prep_query($data);

            //prepend $format in to $values
            array_unshift($values, $format);

            //prepare statements
            if ( !( $stmt = $this->cxn->prepare("INSERT INTO {$table} ({$fields}) VALUES ({$placeholders})") ) ) {
                echo "Error preparating the query: (" . $this->cxn->errno . ") " . $this->cxn->error;
            }

            //Dinamically binding
            if ( !call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $this->ref_values($values)) ) {
                echo "Error binding parameters: (" . $this->cxn->errno . ") " . $this->cxn->error;
            }

            //execute the query
            if (!$stmt->execute()) {
                echo "Error executing the insert query: (" . $this->cxn->errno . ") " . $this->cxn->error;
            }

            //Check for succesful insertion
            if ( $stmt->affected_rows ) {
                return $stmt->insert_id;
            }

            return false;

        }

        /**
         * Update a row in a table
        * @param  string $table
        * @param  array $data
        * @param  string $format
        * @param  array $where
        * @param  string $where_format
        * @return boolean
         */
        public function update( $table, $data, $format, $where, $where_format ) {

            if ( empty($table) || empty($data) ) {
                return false;
            }

            //cast to array
            $data = (array) $data;
            $format = (array) $format;
            $where_format = (array) $where_format;

            //Build format string
            $format = $this->build_format($format);
            $where_format = $this->build_format($where_format);
            $format .= $where_format;

            //prepare data
            list($fields, $placeholders, $values) = $this->prep_query($data, 'update');
            list($where_clause, $where_values) = $this->prep_where($where);

            //prepend $format onto $values
            array_unshift($values, $format);
            $values = array_merge($values, $where_values);

            //prepare statements
            if ( !( $stmt = $this->cxn->prepare("UPDATE {$table} SET {$placeholders} WHERE ({$where_clause})") ) ) {
                echo "Error preparating the update query: (" . $this->cxn->errno . ") " . $this->cxn->error;
            }
            //bind params
            if ( !call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $this->ref_values($values)) ) {
                echo "Error binding parameters: (" . $this->cxn->errno . ") " . $this->cxn->error;
            }

            //execute
            if (!$stmt->execute()) {
                echo "Error executing the query: (" . $this->cxn->errno . ") " . $this->cxn->error;
            }

            //Check for succesful insertion
            if ( $stmt->affected_rows ) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;

        }

        /**
         * Delete a row from a table
         * @param  string $table
         * @param  string|array $where
         * @param  string|array $where_format
         * @return false
         */
        public function delete( $table, $where = '', $where_format = '' ) {

            if ( !is_array( $where ) ) {
                $where = array( 'ID' => $where );
                $where_format = 'i';
            }

            $where_format = (array) $where_format;
            $where_format = $this->build_format($where_format);

            //prepare data
            list($where_clause, $where_values) = $this->prep_where($where);

            //prepend $format onto $values
            $values = $where_values;
            array_unshift($values, $where_format);

            //prepare statements
            if ( !( $stmt = $this->cxn->prepare("DELETE FROM {$table} WHERE {$where_clause}") ) ) {
                echo "Error preparating the delete query: (" . $this->cxn->errno . ") " . $this->cxn->error;
            }

            //bind params
            if ( !call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $this->ref_values($values)) ) {
                echo "Error binding parameters: (" . $this->cxn->errno . ") " . $this->cxn->error;
            }

            //execute
            if (!$stmt->execute()) {
                echo "Error executing the query: (" . $this->cxn->errno . ") " . $this->cxn->error;
            }

            //Check for succesful insertion
            if ( $stmt->affected_rows ) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;

        }

        /**
         * Select a row from a table
         * @param  string $table
         * @param  string $where
         * @param  string $where_format
         * @return array
         */
        public function select( $table, $where = '', $where_format = '' ) {

            if ( !is_array( $where ) ) {
                $where = array( 'ID' => $where );
                $where_format = 'i';
            }

            $where_format = (array) $where_format;
            $where_format = $this->build_format($where_format);

            //prepare data
            list($where_clause, $where_values) = $this->prep_where($where);

            //prepend $format onto $values
            $values = $where_values;
            array_unshift($values, $where_format);
            //prepare statements
            if ( !( $stmt = $this->cxn->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$table} WHERE {$where_clause}") ) ) {
                echo "Error preparating the query: (" . $this->cxn->errno . ") " . $this->cxn->error;
            }

            //bind params
            if ( !call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $this->ref_values($values)) ) {
                echo "Error binding parameters: (" . $this->cxn->errno . ") " . $this->cxn->error;
            }

            //execute
            if (!$stmt->execute()) {
                echo "Error executing the query: (" . $this->cxn->errno . ") " . $this->cxn->error;
            }

            $results = $this->get_results($stmt);
            if ( $results ) {
                return $results;
            } else {
                throw new \Exception('Invalid query, no results founds.');
            }

        }

        /**
         * Select multiple row from a table
         * @param  string $table
         * @param  string $where
         * @param  string $where_format
         * @return array
         */
        public function select_array( $table, $where = '', $where_format = '' ) {

            if ( !is_array( $where ) ) {
                $where = array( 'ID' => $where );
                $where_format = 'i';
            }

            $where_format = (array) $where_format;
            $where_format = $this->build_format($where_format);

            //prepare data
            list($where_clause, $where_values) = $this->prep_where($where);

            //prepend $format onto $values
            $values = $where_values;
            array_unshift($values, $where_format);

            //prepare statements
            if ( !( $stmt = $this->cxn->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$table} WHERE {$where_clause}") ) ) {
                echo "Error preparating the query: (" . $this->cxn->errno . ") " . $this->cxn->error;
            }

            //bind params
            if ( !call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $this->ref_values($values)) ) {
                echo "Error binding parameters: (" . $this->cxn->errno . ") " . $this->cxn->error;
            }

            //execute
            if (!$stmt->execute()) {
                echo "Error executing the query: (" . $this->cxn->errno . ") " . $this->cxn->error;
            }

            $results = $this->get_results($stmt, 'array');
            if ( $results ) {
                return $results;
            } else {
                throw new \Exception('Invalid query, no results founds.');
            }

        }

        /**
         * Select all the rows from a table
         * @param  string $table
         * @return array
         */
        public function select_all( $table ) {

            //prepare statements
            if ( !( $stmt = $this->cxn->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$table}") ) ) {
                echo "Error preparating the query: (" . $this->cxn->errno . ") " . $this->cxn->error;
            }

            //execute
            if (!$stmt->execute()) {
                echo "Error executing the query: (" . $this->cxn->errno . ") " . $this->cxn->error;
            }

            $results = $this->get_results($stmt, 'array');
            if ( $results ) {
                return $results;
            } else {
                throw new \Exception('Invalid query, no results founds.');
            }

        }

        /**
         * Get results from a query
         * @param  object $stmt
         * @param  string $type
         * @return array
         */
        private function get_results($stmt, $type = 'string') {
            $stmt->store_result();
            $meta = $stmt->result_metadata();

            while ( $field = $meta->fetch_field() ) {
                $params[] = &$row[$field->name];
            }

            call_user_func_array( array( $stmt, 'bind_result' ), $params );

            $results = array();
            while ( $stmt->fetch() ) {
            foreach( $row as $key => $val ) {
                $c[$key] = $val;
            }
            if ($type === 'array') {
                $results[] = $c;
            } else {
                $results = $c;
            }
            }
            if ( !empty( $results) ) return $results;
            return false;
        }

        /**
         * Build the format string for the query values
         * @param  array $format
         * @return string
         */
        private function build_format( $format ) {
            $format = implode('', $format);
            $format = str_replace('%', '', $format);
            return $format;
        }

        /**
         * Prepare data for a query
         * @param  array $data
         * @param  string $type
         * @return array
         */
        private function prep_query($data, $type = 'insert') {

            //instantiate $fields and $placeholders for looping
            $fields = '';
            $placeholders = '';
            $values = array();

            //loop through $data and build $fields, $placeholders and $values
            foreach ( $data as $field => $value ) {
                $fields .= "{$field},";
                $values[] = $value;

                if ( $type == 'update' ) {
                    $placeholders .= $field . '=?,';
                } else {
                    $placeholders .= '?,';
                }
            }

            //normalize $fields and $placeholder for inserting
            $fields = substr( $fields, 0, -1 );
            $placeholders = substr( $placeholders, 0, -1 );

            return array( $fields, $placeholders, $values );
        }

        /**
         * Prepare where data for a query
         * @param  array $where
         * @return array
         */
        private function prep_where($where) {
            $where_clause = '';
            $where_values = array();
            $count = 0;
            foreach ($where as $field => $value) {
                if ( $count > 0 ) {
                    $where_clause .= ' AND ';
                }
                $where_clause .= $field . '=?';
                $where_values[] = $value;
                $count++;
            }
            return array($where_clause, $where_values);
        }

        /**
         * Create references for query values
         * @param  array $array
         * @return array
         */
        private function ref_values( $array ) {
            $refs = array();
            foreach ( $array as $key => $value ) {
                $refs[$key] = &$array[$key];
            }
            return $refs;
        }

        /**
         * Hash a password
         * @param  string $password
         * @param  string $nonce
         * @return string
         */
        public function hash_password($password, $nonce) {
            $secureHash = hash_hmac('sha512', $password . $nonce, SITE_KEY);
            return $secureHash;
        }

        /**
         * Close the connection to database
         */
        private function close() {
            if ( !$this->cxn->close() ) {
                die('Can\'t close the connection');
            }
        }

    }

}

?>
```

Then I use these methods in my model classes, like in this example of the Page class:

Models/Page.php

```
public function insert( $data ) {

            //prepare data
            list($data, $cats, $tags) = $this->prep_data($data);

            //insert the post
            $post = $this->db->insert( $this->table, $data, 'sssss' );

            //insert the post-cats relations
            if ( isset( $cats ) ) {
                foreach ( $cats as $cat ) {
                    $relation = array(
                        'post_id' => $post,
                        'term_id' => $cat,
                    );
                    $this->db->insert( 'term_relationships', $relation, 'ii' );
                }
            }

            //insert the post-tags relations
            if ( isset( $tags ) ) {
                foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
                    $relation = array(
                        'post_id' => $post,
                        'term_id' => $tag,
                    );
                    $this->db->insert( 'term_relationships', $relation, 'ii' );
                }
            }

            return $post;
        }
```

Here is the whole code: [Github](https://github.com/genethic/OOP-MVC-CMS)

Comment: Try checking if `$this->cxn == NULL`  before assigning it to `new \mysqli( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME );`

Comment: I try that but doesn't work, the warning still showing. I will update the code with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using constants to connect to the DB - which means the class will only support connections with one set of parameters.

You could make the connection static and then you will only get one per script no matter how many times you instantiate the class. [The PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) provides a good explanation of static usage.

This won't scale if you require a second connection to a different DB, but by then you'll be needing to re-factor the class a little anyway and shift the other constants.

```
if ( !class_exists( 'DB' ) ) {

class DB {

    // make $cxn a static property shared between instances of this class
    private static $cxn = null;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->connect();
    }

    private function connect() {
        if(!is_null(self::$cxn)) {
            // a connection has already been tried, and succeeded
            return;
        }

        self::$cxn = new \mysqli( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME );
        if ( self::$cxn->connect_error ) {
            die( "Connection failed: " . self::$cxn->connect_errno . ' ' . self::$cxn->connect_error );
        }
    }
```

Comment: this give me a lot of errors I would need to make a lot of changes in my code to use the static, and the warning still show

Comment: Errors are: Strict Standards: Accessing static property Core\DB::$cxn as non static in /var/www/html/Projects/CMS4/lib/DB.php on line 15

Comment: That helps. I've updated the code to correctly reference the static property. I've also linked to the manual which gives more in depth information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function for close connections

```
   function __destruct()
     {
         //destroy open connection
     }
```

Comment: I try closing connection on the class destructor but give me another error: Warning: mysqli::close(): Couldn't fetch mysqli